# Circular progress view with outside stroke

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to create a circular progress view that has stroke outside. But my stroke starts from inside of the view instead of the start from the outside it like border. How can I solve it?

**My code:**

```
var progressLayer = CAShapeLayer()
var trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()

var progressLineWidth: CGFloat = 20
var progressColor = UIColor.green
var progress: Float = 0.5

let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2.0 - 2, y: frame.size.height / 2.0 - 2), radius: (frame.size.width) / 2, startAngle: -(.pi / 2), endAngle: .pi * 1.5, clockwise: true)

trackLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
trackLayer.lineWidth = 10
trackLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0
trackLayer.lineDashPattern = [4,4]
trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

progressLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
progressLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
progressLayer.strokeColor = progressColor.cgColor
progressLayer.lineWidth = progressLineWidth
progressLayer.strokeEnd = CGFloat(progress)
progressLayer.strokeStart = 0
progressLayer.lineDashPattern = [4,4]
layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
```

**Result:**

[image]

**What I want to achive:**

[image]

**Gray and green strokes should start from the outside of the red circle.**

Comment: Do you want the red background? If yes, why not put the red circle above, or use a mask to hide that part?

Comment: No there will be no red background it will be clear to see what is behind it. It is like faceId scan animation screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Demo]

You can subtract the middle circle by a simple mask like:

```
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath.subtracting(circlePath.cgPath)
layer.mask = maskLayer
```

---

#### Full working code: - (updated to support iOS below 16)

```
class CircularProgressBarView: UIView {
    var progress: CGFloat = 0 { didSet { layoutSubviews() } }
    var progressLineWidth: CGFloat = 20 { didSet { layoutSubviews() } }
    var progressColor = UIColor.green { didSet { layoutSubviews() } }
    var pattern: [NSNumber] = [4,4] { didSet { layoutSubviews() } }

    private var customLayer = CALayer()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        customLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        customLayer = CALayer()

        let bounds = CGRect(
            x: progressLineWidth,
            y: progressLineWidth,
            width: bounds.width - progressLineWidth*2,
            height: bounds.height - progressLineWidth*2
        )

        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds)

        let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        trackLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineWidth = progressLineWidth
        trackLayer.lineDashPattern = pattern
        trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        customLayer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

        let progressLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        progressLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        progressLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        progressLayer.strokeColor = progressColor.cgColor
        progressLayer.lineWidth = progressLineWidth * 2
        progressLayer.strokeEnd = progress
        progressLayer.lineDashPattern = pattern
        customLayer.addSublayer(progressLayer)

        let containerPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds)
        containerPath.append(circlePath.reversing())
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = containerPath.cgPath
        customLayer.mask = maskLayer

        layer.addSublayer(customLayer)
    }
}
```

<sub>Of course you can rotate the whole layer (or view) to make it start from 12 O'clock</sub>

Comment: This produces quarter circle. https://imgur.com/a/EbkystJ Also inside of the circle will be clear color to see what's behind it there will be camera view.

Comment: No its not as you can clearly see that my demo image is far different from yours. Your new issue is with the code related to adding this view to its superview which you did not provide. You can provide the full code so I can see if I can help you with that too.

Comment: Yeah of course you can check it here: https://codeshare.io/dee7oy

Comment: I have decided to rewrite original to help you with the layout issues as well

Comment: Is there a way achive the same thing without using subtracting method? Because it requires ios 16.

Comment: @TolgayToklar Update supporting iOS below 16

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom view where you can set all properties as per your requirement

```
class CircularProgressBar: UIView {
    
    var progress: CGFloat = 0.2  {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    
    var progressColor: UIColor = .red {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    
    var nonProgressColor: UIColor = .lightGray {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    
    var lineWidth: CGFloat = 10 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    
    var lineSpacing: CGFloat = 3 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    
    var lineHeight: CGFloat = 15 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    
    var centerCircleRadius: CGFloat = 5 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: rect.height / 2)
        let radius = min(rect.width, rect.height) / 2.5 - lineWidth
        
        // Draw track
        let trackPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        nonProgressColor.setStroke()
        trackPath.lineWidth = lineWidth
        trackPath.stroke()
        
        // Draw lines
        let numLines = 60 // Adjust as needed
        let angleIncrement = CGFloat.pi * 2 / CGFloat(numLines)
        let lineStartRadius = radius + lineWidth / 2
        let lineEndRadius = lineStartRadius + lineSpacing + 12
        
        for i in 0..<numLines {
            let angle = CGFloat(i) * angleIncrement - CGFloat.pi / 2
            let startPoint = CGPoint(x: center.x + lineStartRadius * cos(angle), y: center.y + lineStartRadius * sin(angle))
            let endPoint = (CGFloat(i) / CGFloat(numLines) <= progress) ? CGPoint(x: center.x + lineEndRadius * cos(angle), y: center.y + (lineEndRadius + 5) * sin(angle)) : CGPoint(x: center.x + lineEndRadius * cos(angle), y: center.y + lineEndRadius * sin(angle))
            let linePath = UIBezierPath()
            linePath.move(to: startPoint)
            linePath.addLine(to: endPoint)
            linePath.lineWidth = lineWidth
            if CGFloat(i) / CGFloat(numLines) <= progress {
                progressColor.setStroke()
            } else {
                nonProgressColor.setStroke()
            }
            linePath.stroke()
        }
    }
}
```

Result  : [check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9Hr4.png)